# how to get bootstrap date picker format as 03-june-2017

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

here is my java script,where i want date as 03-june-2017 i am not able to do it please give me solution.

```
<div class="form-group" >
            <div class='input-group date'  >
                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker();
 format:
 });
  </script>
```

how to use format ?.i searched it but i did not get solution,  can any one give me solution.

Comment: Did you use [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?

Comment: its datepicker only id i gave as datetimepicker sorry for making you confused .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 });
</script>
```

**Or**

```
    $("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

**Or**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "d M,y" });
```

Comment: @bharathvarma try now

Comment: i want with bootstrap datepicker even with d M,Y out put is 01 jun,2017 but the requirment is 01-june-2017

Answer (score 2):

Based on [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format), You can use `M` or `MM` in `format` to get month name (try it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sof8krqr/)):

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <div class='input-group date'  >
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if i use  M or MM in both the cases out put is 01--2017  month is missing,it have to be(01-june-2017).thank you@Mohammad Hamedani

Comment: What's your datepicker version?

Comment: sorry @Mohammad Hamedani when i downloaded that it did not gave any  version which is convenient for this format.

Comment: Can provide any link of your library that used as datepicker?

Comment: brother it was long back i downloaded that js, if you do not mind share me the link which will have the supported version, thank you for yoir Patience @  Mohammad Hamedani

Answer (score -1):

Use `'dd-MM-yyyy'` string for [format option](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) value. You could try this solution using the snippet below.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({format:'dd-MM-yyyy'});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it.